# Pop up new text box after click on "Others" from dropdown and database captured that new data

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown

I found a way how to pop up a new text box after click on "Others" from the dropdown. But the problem here is database capture "Other" instead of the new data that I key in. For example I key in "Policeman" but it captured "Other" in my database.

```
    <head>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showfield(name){
    if(name=='Other')document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Other: <input type="text" 
    name="other" />';
    else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
   }

 </script> 
 </head>
    <form action="https://apps3.xendsys.com/emv3/index.php/lists/xl080bdvq5cc8/subscribe" method="post">
   <div class="box box-primary borderless">
  <div class="box-header">
  <h3 class="box-title">Website Subscribers</h3>
  </div>
   <select name="OCCUPATION" id="OCCUPATION" 
   onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
      <option selected="selected">Please select ...</option>
      <option value="Student">Student</option>
      <option value="Educator">Educator</option>
      <option value="Designer">Designer</option>
      <option value="Other">Other</option>
   </select>
   <div id="div1"></div>
  <div class="box-footer">
 <div class="pull-right"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" name="yt0" value="Subscribe"/></div>

  <div class="clearfix"> </div>
  </div>
  </div>
    </form>
```

What should I change ya?

Comment: You should post your server-side code too. Where do you interact with your database?

Comment: @CoskunOzogul this is just a subscription form, so the action link will redirect to my databse.